# Python (RML) - create a list and then join its elements into string?

Tags: python, list, odoo, rml

I'm trying to generate a list in RML report from one2many lines fields. There is `sale.order` class and `sale.order.line` (this one is related with another class that stores taxes names).

So in rml report I tried something like this:

```
[[ ', '.join(list.append(x.name) for x in l.tax_id) ]]
```

Where l is equivalaned to `order_line`(this field relates with `sale.order.line` class) and tax_id relates with taxes table where I need to get all taxes names and append it to string.
In rml I can't simply define list and then try some for to append it, because it gives me incorrect syntax error.

After trying that line, I got this error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'append' requires a 'list' object but received a 'unicode'
```

So then I tried wrapping `x.name` with list(), and then I got this error:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I also tried with lambda, but wasn't able to create list from it too, it would output generator object, if I wrapped lambda expression with `list()`, then it would output function objects. It's clear that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure how to simply get a list that I could then create string from it?

**Update**
I also tried this one:

```
[[ ', '.join(map(lambda x: x.name, l.tax_id)) ]]
```

But it works correctly with only one `order line`. If there are more than one, then it shows the last lines results (forgeting about the previous ones). So it's the same thing that it does not create list.

**Sample data** (simplified)

**Tax table**

```
|id|name|
 1 | tax1
 2 | tax2
 3 | tax3
```

**Sale Order**(as order_line as one2many I just showed like this)

```
|id|order_line|
|1 |3,4|
```

**Sale Order Line**

```
|id|tax_id|
|3 |1,2
|4 |2,3
```

So giving this sample for such sale order with those order lines and taxes it should output this:

`tax1, tax2, tax3` (it should not output the same tax name more than once)

And currently it outputs like this:
`tax2, tax3`

Comment: Remove the `list.append` call, just `x.name` is enough.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary then it works the same as with my lambda example. It only outputs information from last line, because I think it does not save previous results (no were to store). Maybe I should somehow do two for iterations? One to iterate inside the order line, and then the upper for to iterate over order lines?

Comment: Please post some sample data then and also expected output.

Comment: But if I would do two for loops I still would need to check somehow previous elements to check if those are the same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [[ ', '.join(list(set(tax.name for line in o.order_line for tax in line.tax_id if tax))) ]]

Comment: This one worked - `[[ ', '.join(list(set(tax.name for line in o.order_line for tax in line.tax_id))) ]]`. Can you modify your answer? Because if I used square brackets inside `set`, it gave me syntax error. Also `if tax` seems to not matter, because it gives me same result with it or without it. It does not duplicate tax names even if I don't use `if tax` part.

Comment: Modified. `if tax` is used so that if there is any sale order line with no tax should not show the error.